# Regression starting at 4.7.20 causes redirect to Drupal home page with Drupal error status displayed: "E-mail address field is required."

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, civimember

Not good, not good at all. This weekend discovered the source of new member join fails. Defect similar sounding to CRM-4998 "Setup a Personal Campaign Page - Account Information step is not working in Drupal OR Joomla with default Supporter profile" has bitten our site.

Drupal 6.x latest

CiviCRM 4.7.x latest

Our new member join process is rather complicated. CiviContribution + CiviMembership + CiviProfile + creating a Drupal CMS account. When I try to confirm a new member join, it lands me back at the site homepage with the same error message as CRM-4998 stated: "E-mail address field is required." There is one email address field on our new member join form, and I have it correctly populated.

Nothing shows up for the failing transaction in the CiviCRM.log file. Tail of the log is:

```
Jul 09 07:46:46  [info] Running task: Cleanup old files
Jul 09 07:46:46  [info] Running task: Begin Upgrade to 4.7.21
Jul 09 07:46:47  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 4.7.21
Jul 09 07:46:47  [info] Running task: Finish Upgrade DB to 4.7.21
```

Suggestions please where to begin searching.

I am thankful,

Michael Lueck